# Using core animation hides my window grow box

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I have a NSView that's hosting a CALayer. When the NSView overlaps with the window's grow box the grow box no longer draws.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As a work around I'm now drawing the resize indicator my self.